# MFC: what is needed to trigger menu action by posting message?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I have a menu item related to a function.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyDoc, CDocument)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_ACTION, &CMyDoc::OnFileAction)
```

Somewhere in my code, I try to run this function by posting message like

```
AfxGetMainWnd()->PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, 0, ID_FILE_ACTION);
```

But nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The menu item ID for a [`WM_COMMAND` message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-command) is in the *low word* of `wParam`, *not* in `lParam`! (And `lParam` should be zero.) So, try this:

```cpp
    AfxGetMainWnd()->PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM(ID_FILE_ACTION, 0), 0);
```